# SQL JOIN doubling values

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, group-by, ssms

I have two temp tables with following data:

### temp_aht

[image]

### temp_1

[image]

I use this query to join the two tables on column Incident:

```
    Select 
       count(distinct a.Incident) as nr_of_tickets 
      ,a.[Service]
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN a.status_switch  IN ('Assigned » In Progress','Assigned » Pending','Assigned » Resolved','Assigned » Closed') THEN a.TotalSeconds ELSE NULL END) AS AssignedTime
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN a.status_switch  IN ('In Progress » Assigned','In Progress » Assigned','In Progress » Pending','In Progress » Resolved') THEN a.TotalSeconds ELSE NULL END) AS ProgressTime
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN a.status_switch  IN ('Pending » Assigned','Pending » In Progress') THEN a.TotalSeconds ELSE NULL END) AS PendingTime
      ,sum(b.Creation) as Creation
      ,sum(b.[Call duration]) as [Call duration] 
 from ##temp_aht as a inner join ##temp_1 as b on a.incident = b.incident_id
 group by a.[Service],b.Creation,b.[Call duration]
```

If I join the tables with the above query the SUMs won't be correct.
I think this is because in both tables I have multiple rows with the same Incident id.

But how can I join the table and take only the first row from ##temp_1 if a match is found ?

Comment: Yes, they would. That is because your right table lists the employees and their current/current assignments, no?

Comment: Why are some columns in the aggregate and group by?

Comment: If you are smashing by two different groupings anyway...why not use two group boys??

Comment: Please provide a desired result example. That would be helpful.

Comment: What you've asked for here will give you odd results as well, you're aggregating creation and call duration from the second table, so you can't just take the first matched row or you'll only get one value, see Gordon's answer for what you probably want, although Sagi's will give what you've asked for

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you have multiple rows for each incident in both tables.  This is further complicated by the fact that you are joining on one column (incident) and then aggregating by another (service).

Then, your `group by` includes aggregated columns from the `b` table, which doesn't make sense.

The solution is to aggregate both tables *before* doing the join.  I think this is what you want:

```
select sum(nr_of_tickets), a.[Service],
       sum(AssignedTime) as AssignedTime,
       sum(ProgressTime) as ProgressTime,
       sum(PendingTime) as PendingTime,
       sum(b.Creation) as Creation,
       sum(b.[Call duration]) as [Call duration] 
from (select a.Service, count(distinct a.Incident) as nr_of_tickets,
             SUM(CASE WHEN a.status_switch  IN ('Assigned » In Progress','Assigned » Pending','Assigned » Resolved','Assigned » Closed') THEN a.TotalSeconds END) AS AssignedTime
             SUM(CASE WHEN a.status_switch  IN ('In Progress » Assigned','In Progress » Assigned','In Progress » Pending','In Progress » Resolved') THEN a.TotalSeconds END) AS ProgressTime,
             SUM(CASE WHEN a.status_switch  IN ('Pending » Assigned','Pending » In Progress') THEN a.TotalSeconds END) AS PendingTime
      from ##temp_aht a
      group by a.Incident, a.Service
     ) a inner join
     (select b.incident, 
             sum(b.Creation) as Creation,
             sum(b.[Call duration]) as [Call duration]
      from ##temp_1 b
      group by b.incident
     ) b
     on a.incident = b.incident_id
group by a.[Service]
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response.I was sick.